# Breaking up an equation in the align* environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I'm trying to produce the following formatting without use of all the `\quad` commands to get the last equation to align nicely across the break up (`a(x)`, `b(x)`, and `c(x)` are actually really long expressions).  I searched the internet for quite bit to no avail.  Any ideas?

```
\begin{align*}
f & = \int a(x) ) dx\\
%
& = \int b(x) \\
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \cdot c(x) dx\\
%
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `\hphantom` to obtain the correct horizontal spacing without typesetting anything:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f & = \int a(x) dx \\
& = \int b(x) \\
& \hphantom{{}=\int b(x)}\cdot c(x) dx
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice touch to use the `\hphantom` command -- it combines the `\phantom` and `\smash` commands I use in my answer!

Comment: Yes - I originally commented on that in your solution, but removed it.

Answer (score 4):

Your method is almost correct; if `b(x)` and `c(x)` represent here long expressions, it would be nonsense trying to align the `\cdot` with the end of `b(x)`.

I would use a simple `\quad`, but with a slight improvement:

```
\begin{align*}
f & = \int a(x)\,dx\\
& = \int b(x) \\
& \mathrel{\phantom{=\int}}\quad {}\cdot c(x)\,dx
\end{align*}
```

In this way the `\quad` will start just after the integral sign on the line above and the vertical spacing of the three lines will be uniform. The `{}` inserts a dummy object that makes the `+` into a binary operation symbol.

"Realistic" example:

```
\begin{align*}
f & = \int \cos(x-a)\,dx\\
& = \int (\cos a\cos x \\
& \mathrel{\phantom{=\int}}\quad{} + \sin a\sin x)\,dx
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it improve intelligibility to add a left parenthesis after the integral sign on the middle line and a right parenthesis between the end of the integrand and the "dx" term on the final line?

Comment: @Mico Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one `&` per line, which allows you to align items along different 'anchors':

```
\begin{align*} f & = \int a(x) dx &\\%
& = \int b(x) \\
& & \cdot c(x) dx%
\end{align*}
```

or you can stretch them a bit farther apart by using `flalign` instead of `align`:

```
\begin{flalign*} f & = \int a(x) dx &\\%
& = \int b(x) \\
& & \cdot c(x) dx%
\end{flalign*}
```

See which suits you better.

Comment: the distance between c(x) and the equal sign is far.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below meets your requirements. The `\phantom{\phantom{=\int b(x)}` command inserts an invisible block of the same width as its contents (i.e., of the line above), and the `\smash{...}` command prevents the invisible block from taking up too much vertical space. (Try the code without the `\smash` command to see the effect on the spacing between lines 2 and 3 of the `align*` environment.) Finally, the extra `{}` snippet inside the `\phantom` command is there to tell TeX to treat the (otherwise invisible) equal sign as a "normal" math-relational operator.

Separately, I've eliminated a stray right parenthesis from the first line and added a couple of "thin space" commands, `\,`, to provide a bit of separation between the integrands and the "dx" terms; doing so tends to improve legibility (and it's a practice followed by many mathematicians, including Don Knuth -- the creator of TeX). :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f &= \int a(x) \,dx \\
  &= \int b(x) \\
  &\smash{\phantom{{}=\int b(x)}}\cdot c(x)\,dx
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your alignment is not 100% correct if due to the incorrect setting of `=` as the first item of `\phantom`. Typeset two lines (one with and one without the `\hphantom` to see the marginal difference.

Comment: Thanks, @Werner. I've changed this piece in the meantime, and added an explanation of what the `{}` snippet does for the alignment of the "invisible" equal sign. :-)

Comment: nice touch on the use of the thin space command. Thanks!

Comment: Not `\smash{\phantom{...}}`, but `\hphantom`. On the other hand, `\phantom` would give uniform spacing for the lines.

Comment: @egreg: `\smash{\phantom{...}}` and `\hphantom{...}` yield the same result in this case, no? See also the comment I left on @Werner's answer.

Comment: Yes, but TeX has to do the same work twice, so the formula in the inner braces has to be typeset eight times: both `\smash` and `\phantom` use `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks for this followup.

Answer (score 0):

If both b(x) and c(x) are long enough, you can use this:

```
\begin{multline*}
\begin{aligned}
f &= \int a(x) \,dx\\
  &= \int b(x) 
\end{aligned}
\\
{}\cdot c(x)\,dx
\end{multline*}
```

Or just replace multiple `\quad`s with `\hspace{10em}`